# add column totals based on another colums id

Tags: mysql

Looked and searched all over, but can't seem to find an answer to my problem.

I need to get the total amount of each item (ItemID) regardless of which user (UserID) has them.

I know how to get the total of the Quantity column, i just can't figure out how to do that for each item id.

```
+-----------+------------+---------------+
|   UserID  |   ItemID   |   Quantity    |
+-----------+------------+---------------+
|         1 |         13 |              7|
|         2 |         12 |              4|
|         3 |         12 |             12|
|         4 |         13 |              2|
|         5 |          9 |              1|
|         6 |          8 |              1|
|         7 |          8 |              9|
+-----------+------------+---------------+
```

i.e. 13 = 9, 12 = 16, 9 = 1, 8 = 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `COUNT()` function

```
SELECT `ItemID`, SUM(`Quantity`) as total 
FROM `test`
GROUP BY `ItemID` 
ORDER BY `ItemID` DESC
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4c2cf/4)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
select ItemId,sum(Quantity) as total from Items Group By ItemID
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
select itemid,sum(quantity) from table1 group by itemid;
```